# Quick Questions for Evaluating an Integral

Tags: calculus

The calculus shown below is confusing to me. I understand the first step, moving m outside the integral and rewriting in terms of dt, but how does the rest of the evaluation work?

$$\int m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}dx = m\int\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\frac{dx}{dt}dt = \frac{m}{2}\int\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2dt = \frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\mathrm{constant}$$

Thank you in advance. For reference, this is from Quantum Chemistry by McQuarrie.

Comment: **Hint:** Chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $v=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$,

$$\int\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}dx=\int\frac{dv}{dt}dx=\int (dv)\frac{dx}{dt}=\int v\,dv=\frac12v^2.$$

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.